# Netbeans Ruby on rails autocomplete does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans6.8

I am using Netbeans v6.8 on Ubuntu 9.10 for Ruby on Rails development.

My problem is that autocomplete works very inconsistently. For example, when I hit ctrl+space after typing "File.", I get all the methods neatly defined at the top in bold that can be called on the class. This list is demarcated and followed by all the other hundreds of methods from classes/modules other than File.

But if I hit ctrl+space on some other clause such as "ActionController::Base::logger.", I don't see the methods such as 'info' or 'error' at the top. I just get the generic hundreds of method listed alphabetically (info and error are from the logger class are included in this list but they are interspersed with the rest of the methods and hence not discoverable unless you know what you are looking for).

I initially thought that codecomplete just works for Ruby classes and not Rails but this is not the case as I can get it to work for *some* Rails classes quite accurately and consistenly.

This is getting very frustrating. Can someone please suggest a solution?

If not, can anyone recommend a better (free) IDE that has a better code completion feature?

Answer (score 1):

[Jet Brains Ruby Mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html)

Comment: I would mark this as an answer but I had specifically asked for a free IDE which RubyMine is not.